Calculating absolute Astronomic Field Rotation over a known duration
This is sort of a cross post of my question over on the Astronomy Stack Exchange (https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/57545/calculating-field-rotation-between-two-times).
Example: I'd like to track an object across the sky over 30 or more minutes, using the Skyfield Python library I can easily get the current polar coordinates, and using the below formulae I can calculate the current rotation rate, however this will result in drift over time. How can I find the absolute angle (either delta or current) X minutes after starting observation.
Angular rate of field rotation (degrees/hour)   = K × cos(az) / cos(alt)
K = Observer's Constant = Angular Rate of Rotation of the Earth (degrees/hour) × cos(Observer's latitude)
= 15.04106858 degrees/hour × cos(Observer's latitude)
(15.04106858 degrees/hour = 360° / hours in a Sidereal day)
References for formulae:
https://calgary.rasc.ca/field_rotation.htm

I have a vector angle implementation that works decently but would like to explore other options
